# How to get facebook friends phone,email,address and others friends detail information?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

How to get Facebook friends's phone, email, address and others friends detail information  use Facebook Android SDK 4.4 .

Now I can only get firends id and profile picture by use `https://graph.facebook.com/me/taggable_friends? access_token`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry dude you cant!

Facebook's new API dosent allow you to take any information such as email,phone number etc

The only chances are 
1. me/taggable_friends - Where you can get an Id for tagging your friends and profile picture ( your friends must also use the same app I think)
2. me/invitable friends - This one is for games only to invite people into 
your game

I am unable to find the exact link for you but I've read it in developers.facebook itself.

Here is the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0)